# Different bugs occur depending on the device in the html page implemented with a-frame

Tags: html, augmented-reality, aframe

I ran a-frame's [Location-Based AR demo](https://aframe.io/blog/arjs3/#location-based-ar) by changing only the latitude and longitude, but it didn't work.

Code actually uploaded to the web server (latitude and longitude are hidden)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
　　<head>
    　　<meta charset="utf-8" />
    　　<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    　　<title>Location-based AR.js demo</title>
    　　<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    　　<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-
　　　　component.min.js"></script>
    　　<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene
            vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
            embedded
            arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;"
        >
            <a-text
                value="This content will always face you."
                look-at="[gps-camera]"
                scale="50 50 50"
                gps-entity-place="latitude: I can't show it; longitude: I can't show it;"
            ></a-text>
            <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader> </a-camera>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

The bugs that occur vary depending on the device

On the PC, I disguised the camera with software and overwritten the GPS with developer tools. However, even if I overwrite the gps with any value and reload the page, the object is still displayed.

The camera is displayed normally on the iPad and GPS is enabled, but the Bunso objects displayed on the PC were not displayed in any direction.

A similar bug was found on Chromebooks as on iPad.

The server uses free SSL with XREA's free plan.

I tested the code on [this](https://bagelee.com/programming/location-based-ar/)(Sorry, this page is in Japanese.) page and the code on [this](https://github.com/DaisukeSudo/daisukesudo.github.io/blob/master/samples/arjs/step2/static/index.html) page by replacing the latitude and longitude, but the results were the same and none of them gave the expected results.